# slf4j-log4j12 not packaged by maven with "runtime" scope

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, slf4j, dependency-management

I have a project managed by maven with slf4j-api-1.5.8 and log4j-1.2.14 dependencies.
At runtime, slf4j needs `slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar` to "bridge" output to log4j.

So in `pom.xml` , I add this dependency :

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

After building (war:war) , `log4j-1.2.14.jar` and `slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar` are both added to `WEB-INF/lib` directory , but I cannot find `slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar` within!

I then use "Dependency Hierarchy" to check the resolved dependencies , but cannot find slf4j-log4j12 (so it's not packaged into `WEB-INF/lib`)

What's going wrong here?

environment : maven 3.0-beta1 , m2-eclipse-0.10.0.20100209

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dependency management section is a mechanism for centralizing dependency information, adding a dependency in the dependency management section doesn't make it a dependency of your project by itself, you still need to declare it as dependency:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.8</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```